# Find the closure and the interior of A

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to find the closure and the interior of the set A defined by

$A =${$(x,\sin(x^{-1})) : x \in R-\{0\}$} $\subset$ $R^2$

I don't know how to start. I know that $\sin(x^{-1})$ has it's maximum at 1 and minimum at -1 but the "x" part has infinite values. Any ideas?

Comment: $x$ being unbounded isn’t a problem — remember, for example, that $\mathbb{R}$ is actually closed (and open) within $\mathbb{R}$. The closure is just the union of the set with all of its boundary points, but because the set generated by $x$ basically “fills up” all of $\mathbb{R}$ out at the tails, it doesn’t have any boundary points out there! A boundary point is just any point around which all arbitrarily small neighbourhoods must contain both some point inside your set and some point outside your set, so $\pm \infty$ isn’t a boundary point in any way (and isn’t even in your measure space)!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You need to show that every point on y-axis between -1 and +1 is a limit point of your set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Here x is not possible to contain any arbitrary value as definition given by set A as sin-1(x) is not defined for all x€R-{0] Here x is countably infinite in [-1,1] and we minimum and maximum values of sin-1(x).  As every points of x€[-1,1] and corresponding to this sin-1(x)€[-π/2,π/2] as possible points are limit points and hence closed set. It also exist it's complement of closed set i.e. open sets as (-1,1) and (-π/2,π/2) as interior of A. Int(A)={(-1,1),(-π/2,π/2)} closure of A={[-1,1],[-π/2,1/2]}.